# Azure web app not updating after successful deployment

Tags: c#, .net, azure, api, azure-web-app-service

I have a web app on azure that hosts a web api.
I updated my code on visuall studio then push the updates to the web application on azure.
It says that it is getting successfully updated.
I tried publishing via git and via ftp it is getting successfully updated on the cloud but still returns the old version on get request.

Comment: How you are deploying your App? In windows or Linux App Service plan ?

Comment: Add `WEBSITE_DYNAMIC_CACHE` key with value `0` in Azure App Configuration => Application Settings.

Comment: in windows @Harshitha

Comment: i dont have this configured ```WEBSITE_DYNAMIC_CACHE``` @Harshitha

Comment: Add the setting in `Azure portal` = >Your `App Service` => `Configuration`  => `Application Settings`  => Add new `Application Settings` and check once.

Comment: Tried that but still it didn't work. Note: when i run it locally its output is correct, while on the web app its still the old output. @Harshitha

Comment: Please share your folder structure.

Comment: Didn't understand @Harshitha

Comment: From KUDU Console, could you please share the deployed application folder structure/ files Image.

Comment: Share the file and code which you are trying to update. What exactly you are updating.

Comment: Also set `WEBSITE_LOCAL_CACHE_OPTION` to `Never` and try once.

Comment: In VS under Publish settings options => `File Publish Options` enable the `Remove additional files at destination`.This will ensure that latest code files get updated.[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GnAtp.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- I have created `ASP.Net Web API` and published to Azure.

***Initial Output :***
[image: Initial Output]

- I have made few changes to the Get request.
- In `Publish` window, under `Settings` section click on `Show all settings`.
- Under `File Publish Options`, enable the `Remove additional files at destination` option.

[image]

- This ensures that all the old, cached data gets deleted and updates with the latest code changes.
- Re-deploy the app and restart in Azure portal.

***New Output :***
[image]

- You can even deploy the App using `Import Profile` .
- Create an Azure App service in Azure portal,click on `Download publish profile`.
  [image]
- Enable the option of `Remove additional files at destination` here as well.
- In VS, Import the downloaded publish profile and continue the steps to deploy to Azure.
  [image]

Comment: Thank you @haritha. Downloading the publishing profile and publishing via Vs worked for me.