# AppService publishing is enormously delayed in Visual Studio

Tags: azure, visual-studio, deployment, azure-web-app-service, publish

I'm having a problem since yesterday that I can't publish my ASP.net application from Visual Studio to my Azure AppService.

The process starts and I see that the necessary directories have been created in the AppService folder. However, copying the application files is so slow that I can only speculate that the whole process would probably take 4-5 hours.

FYI, publishing the same application (without customizations) didn't even take 30 seconds until last week.

AppService plan and AppService are set up locally in Germany-West-Central.
Visual Studio Version is 17.4.2

Does anyone know the problem or have an idea to solve it?

Deleting and recreating the Azure resources did not bring any improvement.

my .csproj File:

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <ApplicationIcon />
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <StartupObject />
    <Version>2.1.0.0</Version>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Content Remove="C:\Users\dev\.nuget\packages\foolproof.core\1.1.10\contentFiles\any\net5.0\Scripts\mvcfoolproof.core.js" />
    <Content Remove="C:\Users\dev\.nuget\packages\foolproof.core\1.1.10\contentFiles\any\net5.0\Scripts\mvcfoolproof.jquery.validation.js" />
    <Content Remove="C:\Users\dev\.nuget\packages\foolproof.core\1.1.10\contentFiles\any\net5.0\Scripts\mvcfoolproof.msajax.validation.js" />
    <Content Remove="C:\Users\dev\.nuget\packages\foolproof.core\1.1.10\contentFiles\any\net5.0\Scripts\mvcfoolproof.unobtrusive.js" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <None Include="Views\Home\Index.cshtml" />
    <None Include="Views\Home\Privacy.cshtml" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="FoolProof.Core" Version="1.1.10" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design" Version="6.0.10" />
    <PackageReference Include="NLog" Version="5.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="NLog.Database" Version="5.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="NLog.Schema" Version="5.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="NLog.Web.AspNetCore" Version="5.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Data.SqlClient" Version="4.8.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Management" Version="6.0.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Folder Include="wwwroot\lib\jqueryui\" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="LicenseManager">
      <HintPath>bin\LicenseManager.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Newtonsoft.Json">
      <HintPath>bin\Newtonsoft.Json.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

my appsettings.json file:

```json
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
}
```

[image: my folder structure]

Comment: Could you please share more details about the App Version and Framework.

Comment: @Harshitha The application is compiled for the .net framework 6.0

Comment: How you are deploying your App? Are you getting any Errors ?

Comment: @Harshitha i am doing a pubxml deploy directly from visual studio to my azure app service.

I can't really say if errors will occur. I started the deployment again about 3 hours ago and it is still copying the files to the filesystem of the app service.

As I mentioned before, a deployment of the same application didn't take more than 30 seconds last week. And even if I start the software locally, it runs within a few seconds including compiling.

Comment: Try with `Publish Profile` Once. Create an App Service in Azure first, then download the `Publish Profile` and publish using `Import Profile` from VS. Refer this [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74356510/azure-web-app-not-updating-after-successful-deployment/74360396#74360396) once.

Comment: @Harshitha Thanks for the tip. I have just tried the method. Unfortunately, the publish is already running again for about 10 minutes without any real progress. Is there perhaps a way to publish the application not directly from Visual Studio, but manually via the Azure Portal? Then I would have a workaround to at least continue working :)

Comment: Could you please share your folder structure ? Also share your `appsettings.json` and `.csproj` file.

Comment: Will Work on it and let you know.

Comment: I just tried publishing a locally created zip archive to the AppService via Kudu and zip deploy. Again, the process of unzipping is way too slow and has been running for over an hour now. The zip archive has a size of about 20 MB.
So the bottleneck really seems to be somewhere in Azure.

Comment: Even for me it is taking long time to Publish the sample app.[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QOm41.png)

Comment: I was able to release the software after over 3 hours via Kudu and zip deploy. Once published, it runs as usual. However, I don't want to make the compromise of scheduling 3 hours for each release. I hope Micorosoft gets the problem under control in the next days.

Answer (score 0):

- I have tried to publish the `ASP.NET CORE 6 MVC` project to Azure App Service, Iam able to publish within few minutes without any issues.

[image]

Follow another workaround to Deploy the web Application to Azure App Service.

***Way 1 :***

- In `Azure Portal`, create an App Service.
  [image]
- In Visual Studio, Right click on the project folder and follow the next steps.
- Select the Azure App Service which we have already created in previous step.

[image]

***Output:***
[image]

***Way 2 :***

- In Azure Portal, navigate to the App Service which you have created in 1st step => `Overview` => click on `Download publish profile`.

[image]

- Select `Import Profile`[image]
- Select the Downloaded `publish profile` and continue with the next steps.
  [image]

***My appsettings.json***

```cs
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

<PropertyGroup>  
<TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>  
<Nullable>enable</Nullable>  
<ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>  
</PropertyGroup>

<ItemGroup>  
<PackageReference Include="FoolProof.Core" Version="1.1.10" />  
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design" Version="6.0.10" />  
<PackageReference Include="NLog" Version="5.0.1" />  
<PackageReference Include="NLog.Database" Version="5.0.1" />  
<PackageReference Include="NLog.Schema" Version="5.0.1" />  
<PackageReference Include="NLog.Web.AspNetCore" Version="5.0.0" />  
<PackageReference Include="System.Data.SqlClient" Version="4.8.3" />  
<PackageReference Include="System.Management" Version="6.0.0" />  
</ItemGroup>
```

Comment: @Harshita Can I ask how big your project is? "A few minutes" sounds like a lot to me. As I said, until this week, my project took maybe 30 seconds to publish.
Anyway, I'll give your suggestion a try.

Comment: It is a sample project. I mean few Minutes means it took not more than a min for me.

Comment: Once check your network and also try with another region once.

Comment: Have tried both way 1, and way 2. I tested it on my app as well as the Asp.net sample app and it takes way too long on both, so I had to abort the processes. I also varied the regions of the servers (EU & USA).

Comment: My speed test showed stable 100Mbps download and 30 Mbps upload