# Visual Studio publish Azure app with schedule

Tags: azure, publish

In my current workflow, I make code changes in Visual Studio, push changes to Github, then after hours publish the app to Azure using the Azure app publishing profile (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/quickstart-dotnetcore?tabs=net70&pivots=development-environment-vs#3-update-the-app-and-redeploy), wait 10 minutes and check changes. All the steps are done manually in Visual Studio.

I dislike the "after hours publish ... wait and check" step since it's mindless clicking and waiting, which can be done by a bot. Is there a way to use the same Azure publishing profile, but schedule the publishing to run automatically at a specific time?

Answer (score 0):

There is no scheduling to publish the application automatically, published and reproduced manually. Created a sample web application in visual studio and pushed my application into GitHub.

[image]

I created Web App in azure.

[image]

Then, I connected GitHub to App service by using Authorization.

[image]

The application which I deployed is working fine.

[image]

Then I made changes and updated the application and redeployed there is no conflict of the functioning of the application.

```
 public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
                app.UseSwagger();
                app.UseSwaggerUI();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/newfile");
                app.UseHsts();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });

            app.Run(async (context) =>
            {
                await context.Response.WriteAsync("Hello from my web page!");
            });
        }
    }
   }
```

Output in Local:

[image]

In Azure after deployment:

[image]

Note: Any further clarification required refer this [SO LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74356510/azure-web-app-not-updating-after-successful-deployment/74360396#74360396)
This is another way to publish.

Comment: What does "as per my knowledge" mean in English?